# Preg_match is "ignoring" a capture group delimiter

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

We have thousands of structured filenames stored in our database, and unfortunately many hundreds have been manually altered to names that do not follow our naming convention.  Using regex, I'm trying to match the correct file names in order to identify all the misnamed ones.
The files are all relative to a meeting agenda, and use the date, meeting type, Agenda Item#, and description in the name.

Our naming convention is `yyyymmdd_aa[_bbb]_ccccc.pdf` where:

- **yyyymmdd** is a date (*and may optionally use underscores such as yyyy_mm_dd*)
- **aa** is a 2-3 character Meeting Type code
- **bbb** is an *optional* Agenda Item
- **ccccc** is a freeform variable length description of the file (alphanumeric only)

**Example filenames:**

```
   20200225_RM_agenda.pdf
   20200225_RM_2_memo.pdf
   20200225_SS1_3c_presenTATION.pdf
   20200225_CA_4d_SiGnEd.pdf
   20200225_RM_5_Order1234.pdf
   2021_02_25_EV_Notice.pdf
```

The regex I'm using to match these files is below ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F0hb6R/1)):

`/^(\d{4}[_]?\d{2}[_]?\d{2})_(\w{2,3})_([a-z0-9]{1,3})_?(.+)?.pdf/i`

**The Problem:**
In general, it's working fine, BUT if the Agenda Number ("bbb") is NOT in the filename, the regex captures and returns the first 3 characters of the description.  It seems to me that the 3rd capture group `_([a-z0-9]{1,3})_` is saying *1-3 alphanumeric characters between underscores*, but I don't know how to "force the underscore delimiters", or otherwise tell it that the group may not be there, and that it's now looking at the descriptive text.  This can be seen in the demo code where the first and last filenames do not use an Agenda Number.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional identifier `?` is for the last thing, either a characters or group. So the expression `([a-z0-9]{1,3})_?` makes the underscore optional, but not the preceding group. The solution is to move the underscore into the parenthesis.

```regex
^(\d{4}[_]?\d{2}[_]?\d{2})_(\w{2,3})_([a-z0-9]{1,3}_)?(.+)?.pdf
```

Additionally, the `[_]?` can be simplified to just `_?`, file name periods should be escaped (otherwise they are a wildcard), and I personally like to name my groups using `(?<name>)` syntax. Putting that all together you get:

```regex
^(?<date>\d{4}_?\d{2}_?\d{2})_(?<meeting_type>\w{2,3})_(?<agenda>[a-z0-9]{1,3}_)?(?<description>.+)?\.pdf$
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/BUKCih/1

**Updated:**

I've made some updates based on the comments. I added `$` to the end to force "end of filename" as @Chris Maurer said. This stops `file.pdf.txt` from getting through. I also made a sub-group and moved the name into that group, which allows the trailing underscore to not be included in the named-group. I'm going to leave Chris's other comment about tightening the last matching group alone, although I do agree with it, and the OP might find a couple of non-conforming files if they use `[a-z0-9]+` or similar. I don't remember off-hand if PHP supports POSIX but if so `[:alnum:]` could be used too.

```regex
^(?<date>\d{4}_?\d{2}_?\d{2})_(?<meeting_type>\w{2,3})_((?<agenda>[a-z0-9]{1,3})_)?(?<description>.+)?\.pdf$
```

Updated demo here: https://regex101.com/r/ebmxkF/1

Comment: I LOVE this.I didn't know you could name the Groups like that!! Only one thing, in the returned Agenda, it's including the trailing underscore.  Can that be omitted?

Comment: Two more observations:  1. Your last bullet says alphanumeric only for part ccc but you accept all characters (.+) - maybe make that .+ a bit more restrictive?  2. You should add a $ at the end after the .pdf so you don't match on .pdfxyz.

Comment: Thx! As a Regex Clown, I tend to cannibalize expressions that I have working, not really understanding what is happening half the time.

Comment: I made some updates based on @ChrisMaurer and the OP's notes that should hopefully help